# Trying to get output and prompt to appear on separate lines - Java

Tags: java

I would like to get the Fibonnaci series and the prompt "Type 1 to continue" to appear on separate lines. How can I do that?

Currently the output will be something like:

Fibonnaci Series for the first 5 numbers: 
0 1 1 2 3 Type 1 to continue:

I want it to appear as:

Fibonnaci Series for the first 5 numbers: 
0 1 1 2 3 
Type 1 to continue:

```
import java.util.Scanner; //Import Package

// Fibonacci Series using Recursion
public class Homework {
    static void fib(int n) //fib(n) method 
  {
        int num1 = 0, num2 = 1;
  
        int counter = 0;
  
        while (counter < n) {
  
            System.out.print(num1 + " ");
  
            // Swap
            int num3 = num2 + num1;
            num1 = num2;
            num2 = num3;
            counter = counter + 1;
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[]) //main method
    {
    int n = 1;
        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
        char cont;
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter the number: "); //Ask user to enter the number (value of n)
            n = myObj.nextInt(); // Numerical input 
        try{
            if(n < 0)
            System.out.println("This program does not accept negative numbers");
            
            else
            System.out.println("Fibonnaci Series for the first " + n + " numbers:");
                fib(n); //Call fib(n) to generate Fibonacci Series

               }
            catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
                System.out.println("This program does not accept negative numbers");
              }
            // call fib(n) to generate and print Fibonacci Series for n
            
        System.out.print("Type 1 to continue: "); // Ask user to Type 1 to continue
        cont = myObj.next().charAt(0);
        
    } while(cont == '1');
    

    
}  

}
```

Comment: just use a `System.out.println()` before outputting `"Type 1 to continue: "`.

Comment: This is a great example of why reading the official documentation of the methods you use should always be the first step when encountering behavior you don't want or expect. A simple look at the documentation of the `println` and `print` methods  would have told you what the difference between those 2 is and you could have probably solved this yourself in less time than it took you to write this question.

Comment: Or you can add a newline: `System.out.print("\nType 1 to continue: ");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.out.print()` prints its argument to the system's output stream.
`System.out.println()` does that as well, but adds a "New line"-symbol at the end. That symbol tells the stream, that the next things printed should be put in the next line.

The "New line" symbol can also be written manually as a [escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence) as it's a [control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character). Control characters are special invisble characters that are used for instance for formatting. Escape sequences usually are introduced by a single backslash `\`.
A new line is nowadays introduced by `\n` although there are other options.

TL;DR:
You now have two options:

1. Print the last number in your sequence with `System.out.println()`.
2. You print a `\n` before your `"Type 1 to continue"`

**Appendix:**

Different encodings use different control caracters for introducing new lines:

- Unix: line feed (LF) - `\n`
- Windows: carriage return + line feed (CR LF) - `\r\n`
- Mac OS Classic / Apple II: carriage return (CR) - `\r`

As mentioned before, `\n` should be sufficient for your use case and for most programming tasks.